# Is it new stack snippets feature: show few snippets in one scrollable block?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

If snippets code have four spaces from start line, then in preview shown just

[image]

And in finish view snippets shown in one scrollable block

```
(function(){
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
    })
Snippet 1

    <div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>






    (function(){
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
    })
    Snippet 1

    <div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>






    (function(){
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
    })
    Snippet 1

    <div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>






    (function(){
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
    })
    Snippet 1

    <div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>






    (function(){
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
     // some code
    })
    Snippet 1

    <div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

But if no four spaces:

```js
(function(){
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
})
```

```html
Snippet 1

<div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

```js
(function(){
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
})
```

```html
Snippet 1

<div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

```js
(function(){
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
})
```

```html
Snippet 1

<div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

```js
(function(){
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
})
```

```html
Snippet 1

<div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

```js
(function(){
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
 // some code
})
```

```html
Snippet 1

<div>Many lines of code, Many lines of code,Many lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of codeMany lines of code</div>
```

Each snippet shown separately.

So, is this bug or feature? And how output code for snippets now?

Comment: you mean four spaces from the start(left)?

Comment: yep, from start line

Answer (score 0):

You embedded your snippet into *another code block*. 4 spaces from the start is markdown syntax to insert a code block. So all the individual code snippet sections which had 4 additional spaces ended up inside the outer code block.

You can do the same effect by selecting the snippet code and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or `{}` button in the editor.

It looks like a side effect of incorrect formatting and doesnt look like a bug to me.

Comment: yep, i say about _4 spaces from the start_ in a question, but why in this case, snippets still work, instead just shown as code?

Comment: that is an interesting question.. although it is definitely not new check this sandbox [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298457/347191)

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. It is not new feature.

#### 2. The snippet works but it shown as code.

This is intended behaviour of Markdown. When you add anything after a new line and four spaces, it will be rendered as codeblock.

And snippet is wrapped under some HTML comment. So the snippet will work anyway without considering it's parent. That is the code block.

```
<! -- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<! -- end snippet -->
```

One more thing you may note is that in the above code, the begin snippet and end snippet line won't render even inside code block. (I added a space to show it. Removing the space will render it as)

Comment: "_This is intended behavior of Markdown_" That whatever is indented 4 spaces is rendered as a code block is intended behavior of Markdown. That a snippet is rendered inside the code block is as far is I know not intended behavior, the code block should render the code inside it just like that, even if the code happens to be markdown code for a snippet.

Comment: @DonaldDuck mark down have lots of drawbacks. You can't add a code block after a list unless you used a header `#/##/###` between the list and code. And there are more issues

Comment: @redhand actually you _can_ add code blocks after list by giving 4 _additional spaces_. Its one of the rules of markdown..